# How to stream image to amazon s3 using express js 3.X and angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, amazon-s3

I have used the connect-busboy to get the uploaded file but my script doesn't emits the file event. I am using angular on the client side.

I am using following code:

`req.busboy.on('error', function (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
        console.log(fieldname);
    });
    req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
        //set aws header
        var awsHeader = {
            Bucket: 'Mybucket',
            Key: 'MyImage',
            ContentType: mimetype,
            ACL: 'public-read'
        };
        file.uploadFile(file, awsHeader, function (err, res) {
            console.log(err);
            console.log(res);
        });
    });
    req.busboy.on('finish', function () {
        res.send({status: true, message: "File uploaded succesfully."});
    });
    req.busboy.on('field', function (key, value, keyTruncated, valueTruncated) {
        console.log(key);
    });
    req.pipe(req.busboy);`

The finish event gets fired every time I try to upload file.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you aren't building your file from the multipart form. Before the code below I use node aws-sdk to build an s3Bucket that I can PUT to.

```
req.busboy.on ( 'file', function ( fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype ) {
                if ( !filename ) {
                    // If filename is not truthy it means there's no file
                    return res.status ( 400 ).send ( {error: 'no file'} );
                }

                // Create the initial array containing the stream's chunks
                file.fileRead = [];

                file.on ( 'data', function ( chunk ) {
                    // Push chunks into the fileRead array

                    this.fileRead.push ( chunk );
                    //you can use this if you want to limit file size on ingest                        
                   /*if(this.fileRead.length > 5500000){
                        return res.status(500 ).send({error:"file too large - 5MB max"})
                    }*/
                } );

                file.on ( 'error', function ( err ) {
                    console.log ( 'Error while buffering the stream: ', err );
                } );

                file.on ( 'end', function () {
                    // Concat the chunks into a Buffer
                    var finalBuffer = Buffer.concat ( this.fileRead );

                    req.files[fieldname] = {
                        buffer  : finalBuffer,
                        size    : finalBuffer.length,
                        filename: filename,
                        mimetype: mimetype
                    }


                    var data = {Key: "users/" + req.body.id + '/image/' + req.body.id, Body: req.files[fieldname].buffer, ACL: 'public-read'};
                    //im not sure how you're uploading to s3 but I use this
                     s3Bucket.putObject ( data, function ( err, data ) {
                        if ( err ) {
                            console.log ( err )
                            return res.status ( 400 ).send ( 'error during upload' )
                        } else { //success 
                        }
                    } )
                } );
            } );
```

Comment: The problem with me with my code snippet is that I don't receive file event. The script directly calls the finish event.

Comment: how are you sure you're uploading from client to server then?

Comment: Fixed the issue. I forgot to add name attribute to the input tag.